# Применить стиль ко всем элементам, кроме первого

Tags: html, css

Есть следующий код:

```css
.lib {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lib">
    Content
</div>
<p> Text 1</p>
<div class="lib">
    Content
</div>
<p> Text 2</p>
<div class="lib">
    Content
</div>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы стиль класса `lib` применялся ко всем последующим, кроме первого?

Т.е. результат такой чтоюы первый div игнорировал стили. Такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.lib:not(:first-child) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lib">
  Content
</div>
<p> Text 1</p>
<div class="lib">
  Content
</div>
<p> Text 2</p>
<div class="lib">
  Content
</div>
```